# pandas multi-index divide aggregated counts

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

My raw data is as such

```
    level0  level1  level2
0   0       A       foo
1   0       A       bar
2   0       B       foo
3   0       B       foo
4   0       B       foo
5   0       B       bar
6   1       A       foo
7   1       A       bar
```

And then I try to group the counts as such
df.groupby(['level0', 'level1', 'level2']).size()

to get this

```
level0  level1  level2
0       A       foo            1
                bar            1
        B       foo            3
                bar            1
1       A       foo            1
                bar            1
        B       foo            1
                bar            1
2       A       foo            1
                bar            1
        B       foo            1
                bar            1
```

And now I would simply like to divide the counts of level2 in a ratio of bar/foo to get something like this:

```
level0  level1      {bar counts/foo counts}
0       A           1.00
        B           0.33
1       A           1.00
        B           1.00
2       A           1.00
        B           1.00
```

Perhaps I even setup the original groupby wrong but also tried .div, .apply, etc but having a mental block.  Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
tmp = df.groupby(['level0', 'level1', 'level2']).size()

out = (tmp.unstack().eval('bar/foo')
          .reset_index(name='bar/foo')
      )
```

Or [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
tmp = (df.groupby(['level0', 'level1', 'level2'])
         .size().unstack()
      )

out = (tmp['bar']
       .div(tmp['foo'])
       .reset_index(name='bar/foo')
      )
```

Output:

```
   level0 level1   bar/foo
0       0      A  1.000000
1       0      B  0.333333
2       1      A  1.000000
```

Comment: @Scott no need for a walrus, `out = df.groupby(['level0', 'level1', 'level2']).size().unstack().eval('bar/foo')` is enough. I just split it in two since this was OP's original code ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
# your groupby code
tmp = df.groupby(['level0', 'level1', 'level2']).size() 

# get desired output by xs and div
out = tmp.xs('bar', level=2).div(tmp.xs('foo', level=2))
```

out:

```
level0  level1
0       A         1.000000
        B         0.333333
1       A         1.000000
```